# Imprimir um resultado como Integer caso seja valor inteiro

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Olá! Trabalhei o código adiante... A ideia? É básica: ler três notas e validá-las conforme a tabela:

[tabela de valores][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7nKd.png

Nesta situação, quero que quando a nota resultar em nº inteiro, a ex: 8, em vez de imprimir 8.00, imprima apenas 8 sem pontuação decimal (entretanto, se houver casas decimais diferentes de zero, mostrá-las só com duas casas decimais (agora mostra-se 15 casas); como fazê-lo sem atrapalhar a impressão dos inteiros?)

Como fazer? Da forma adiante não resolveu obviamente (agradeço desde já!!):

```
nota2 = float(input("Digite a segunda nota: "))
nota3 = float(input("Digite a terceira nota: "))

med_art = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3

if med_art % 3 == 0 or med_art % 2 == 0:
    med_art = int(med_art)

if med_art >= 7:
    print("Aluno aprovado com média: ", med_art)
elif med_art < 3:
    print("Aluno reprovado com média: ", med_art)
else:
    print("Aluno em exame com média: ", med_art)
```

Comment: Você pode verificar se o número é inteiro com a função ```med_art.is_integer()```,  e caso seja definir ```decimais = 0```. Exemplo: ```print("{0:.{1}f}".format(med_art, decimais)```.  Mais detalhes em [SoEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577669/python-print-out-float-or-integer)

Answer (score -2):

você poderia por após a variável :.2f, fazendo mostrar somente 2 digitos após o .
Assim você nem precisaria passar pela verificação de números inteiros e também alterando o número após o ponto você pode escolher quantas casas decimais irá aparecer

```py
if med_art >= 7:
    print("Aluno aprovado com média: ", med_art:.2f)
elif med_art < 3:
    print("Aluno reprovado com média: ", med_art:.2f)
else:
    print("Aluno em exame com média: ", med_art:.2f)
```

Answer (score -2):

Poderia também de forma mais "ingênua", comparar o resto da divisão com zero, e se validado usar print(int(nota)), que então o python fará conversão de float para inteiro.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).